# CORS enable on DropWizard & JQuery

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, dropwizard

I am trying to enable CORS on DropWizard (version 0.7)

```
   // Enable CORS headers
    final FilterRegistration.Dynamic cors =
            env.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);

    // Configure CORS parameters
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders",
            "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
    cors.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");

    // Add URL mapping
    cors.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
```

I added this code snippet inside run method.

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/match")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response match(){
```

}

This is my REST method that I call through JQuery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
},
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://localhost:1111/service/matchdevice",
  data: "{\"input\":\"test\"}",
  success: function (result) {
    console.log("success");
  },
  error: function(reserr){
      console.log(reserr);
  }
```

})

This is my JQuery ajax call. I got this error when I send it.

**OPTIONS http://localhost:1111/service/match 400 (Bad Request)send @ jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ (index):24
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1111/service/match. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400**

I googled I couldn't find any solution this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully enabled CORS using different filter.

com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter

code example

```
import com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter;

class Service{
    public static final String CORSFILTER = "CORS";
    private static final String CORS_SUPPORTED_METHODS = "cors.supportedMethods";
    private static final String CORS_SUPPORTS_CREDENTIALS = "cors.supportsCredentials";
    private static final String CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS = "cors.exposedHeaders";
    private static final String CORS_SUPPORTED_HEADERS = "cors.supportedHeaders";
    private static final String CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "cors.allowOrigin";

    @Override
    public void run(final Configuration conf, final Environment env) throws Exception {
        final FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = env.servlets().addFilter(CORSFILTER, CORSFilter.class);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, env.getApplicationContext().getContextPath() + "*");
        filter.setInitParameter(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN, appConfigs.getAllowOrigin());
        filter.setInitParameter(CORS_SUPPORTED_HEADERS, appConfigs.getSupportedHeaders());
        filter.setInitParameter(CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS, appConfigs.getExposedHeaders());
        filter.setInitParameter(CORS_SUPPORTS_CREDENTIALS, appConfigs.getSupportsCredentials());
        filter.setInitParameter(CORS_SUPPORTED_METHODS, appConfigs.getSupportedMethods());      
    }
}
```